# How to enable XBitHack on Apache2 web server (Debian)?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, webserver

I am trying to enable XBitHack on my Apache2 web server running on Debian 10. This is what I put in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /srv/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Options +Includes
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
        XBitHack on
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And after restarting `apache2.service` with systemd, I get told that:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 182 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'XBitHack', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'start' failed.
```

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable [`mod_include`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html) in your server.

Run

```
sudo a2enmod include
```

to symlink `include.load` from `/etc/apache2/mods-available` to the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory and restart your server.

You could also merge the `Options` directive to one line:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```